# save the output of a curl perform to a vector<string> in c++

Tags: c++, curl, vector, libcurl

as my title says, i would like to save the output of a curl perform to a vector..
can any1 please give me a sample code?
i was able to save it into a structure in c. but i want to save it to a vector that too in c++ and i'm a little unconfortable with c++.

```
    vector<string> contents;

size_t handle_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
int numbytes = size*nmemb;
char lastchar = *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1);
*((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = '\0';
contents.push_back((char *)ptr);
*((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = lastchar;  // Might not be necessary.
return size*nmemb;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

vector<string>::iterator i;

CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
    {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, argv[1]);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,handle_data);
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    if (res == 0){
        for(i=contents.begin();i!=contents.end();i++)
            cout << *i << endl;
    }else
        cerr << "Error: " << res << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's a "curl perform"? Is it alive and wiggling? Can I eat it? Or does it have a signature? Why don't you show us what you have, and the signature of the curl functions you need to call, plus the data structures you want the results to end up in? As it is, your question requires knowledge of C++ _and_ curl. And there's considerably fewer C++ programmers knowing curl than there are C++ programmers.

Comment: @sbi, I really don't think you want to eat curl.  On the other hand, I heard that greps are kind of tasty this time of year.

Comment: @sbi : :P .. will give u the snippet that i have.. i think its working.. got a code that saves page into string. edited it to save into vector.

Comment: Are you perchance talking about [curl_easy_perform](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html)?

Comment: This code is ugly as hell, misses a lot of `std::` prefixes to compile, uses C-style casts, and longer exposure to its use of braces and indentation might cause eye cancer. Still, not knowing curl, I have no idea what might be wrong with it algorithmically, and you don't give a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know curl, so I'm going to assume the setup code is correct. So what you want is the callback function to add a string for each block of data received to a vector of strings. This also assumes that the data coming back is 8-bit characters.

```
vector<string> contents;

size_t handle_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    contents.push_back(string(static_cast<const char*>(ptr), size * nmemb));
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

the "call" to string() actually constructs a string object initialized with a pointer and data length.

Answer (score 1):

Try [cURLpp](http://curlpp.org). Here's [an example](http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/56-example-06) that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're probably looking for:

```
size_t handle_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
 {
     size_t numbytes = size*nmemb;

     string temp(static_cast<char*>(ptr), nmemb);

     contents.push_back(temp);

     return numbytes;
 }
```

I'm fairly sure you don't want to write to the `void *ptr` you're passed by the CURL library. And it also looks like you are overwriting the last char of the memory address with `'\0'`, then putting the original value back in there after pushing to the vector. I'm not sure this will work as expected.

Comment: @Ferruccio : guess you were the faster cowboy, so I'll +1 you :)